# Wordpress Is Changing My Image File Names and Adding Numbers (150x150 for example)

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress and the Elementor theme. When I upload images via the Image Box tool, the image shows for a few days, then at some point down the road, the image file names changes on the server and the image is then broken on the site.

On the server, I can see the original image, and then some sort of image size numbers are added to the file name such as 150x150 or 1026x768).

I understand that Wordpress sometimes resizes and adds images, but I have gone into images and entered "0" in setting to prevent it from doing this. I have also gone into functions.php to remove any re-sizing issues, but there was no code related to resizing there.

Comment: I suggest keeping all the different sizes because your theme and some plugins might rely on it. What you should definitely avoid is manually removing from the server because Wordpress will think they still exist and break your site.
After changing settings, initially nothing happens. You still have to run a process to recreate all sizes and save the references in cache. You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ for it.
Also, apart from the settings you can make any plugin or theme(does not have to be in functions.php) can register new image sizes you can't edit.

Answer (score 0):

That's not Wordpress doing it, it's your theme..

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out to be a server load issue. The shared server couldn't handle the requests we were making daily, which affected our image uploads. If anyone else has this issue, upgrade to a dedicated server.